# Mongodb - create ranking of values from field array

Tags: mongodb, sum, aggregate

I am trying to sort a mongodb aggregate I don't what it is happening. I was searching some solution in stack overflow but they didn't work and I don't know why...

My idea is return a ranking of  values from the field array (`tags`). I could achieve the list the sum of values but I can not sort it...

This is the query that I could do and it seems that it works:

```
db.getCollection("metadata").aggregate(
{$unwind: '$tags'},
{$group: {_id:'$tags.name', total: {$sum: 1}}}
);
```

Because I receive this result that It has sense:

```
{
    "_id" : "kite",
    "total" : 1.0
}
{
    "_id" : "piggy bank",
    "total" : 1.0
}
{
    "_id" : "sorrel",
    "total" : 1.0
}
{
    "_id" : "eggnog"
    "total" : 4.0
}
{
    "_id" : "Weimaraner",
    "total" : 1.0
}
{
    "_id" : "bassinet",
    "total" : 15.0
}
{
    "_id" : "squirrel monkey",
    "total" : 1.0
}
{
    "_id" : "bath towel",
    "total" : 6.0
}
```

**TRIES**

When I tried something like this:

```
db.getCollection("metadata").aggregate(
{$unwind: '$tags'},
{$group: {_id:'$tags.name', total: {$sum: 1}}},
{$sort: {total: -1}}
);
```

*RESULT TRY:*

```
{
    "_id" : "baboon",
    "total" : 12.0
}
{
    "_id" : "snow leopard",
    "total" : 4.0
}

{
    "_id" : "green lizard",
    "total" : 5.0
}

{
    "_id" : "Dandie Dinmont",
    "total" : 7.0
}

{
    "_id" : "echidna",
    "total" : 8.0
}

{
    "_id" : "bee eater",
    "total" : 6.0
}
```

or like this:

```
db.getCollection("metadata").aggregate(
{$unwind: '$tags'},
{$group: {_id: { name:'$tags.name', total: {$sum: 1}}}},
{$sort: {total: -1}}
);
```

The result doesn't sort or directly not sum the values...

**EXTRA**

This is the query if I want to list all the entries with the array:

```
db.getCollection('metadata').find({tags: {$exists: true}})
```

And the result is:

```
/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5900af3ff6844d2f7519fe13"),
    "user_id" : 23,
    "company_id" : 1,
    "created" : ISODate("2017-04-26T14:31:27.000Z"),
    "md5file" : "fdd30b1ca52e1c15f330f46c0079498c",
    "path" : "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160605_133703.jpg",
    "image_width" : 3456,
    "image_height" : 4608,
    "originalTags" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "sleeping bag",
            "percentage" : 0.7529412
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "diaper",
            "percentage" : 0.05490196
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "bib",
            "percentage" : 0.039215688
        }
    ],
    "tags" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "sleeping bag",
            "percentage" : 0.7529412
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5900af3ff6844d2f7519fe14"),
    "user_id" : 23,
    "company_id" : 1,
    "created" : ISODate("2017-04-26T14:31:27.000Z"),
    "md5file" : "22612c8bc99d1031146f7c9918555572",
    "path" : "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160605_164243.jpg",
    "image_width" : 4608,
    "image_height" : 3456,
    "originalTags" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "bath towel",
            "percentage" : 0.62352943
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "quilt",
            "percentage" : 0.101960786
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "cradle",
            "percentage" : 0.043137256
        }
    ],
    "tags" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "bath towel",
            "percentage" : 0.62352943
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What result you expect from above collection? because your above query is working as you stated in the question

Comment: I d like to get a ranking for ocurrences for the field  `name`. It means, If I find 5 times 'bath towel' and 1 time 'cradle'l for all `tags` field, the ranking should be first  {5, 'bath towel'}, and after {1, 'cradle'}

Comment: The first "try" works perfectly.

Comment: In my case, trying the first query It doesn't seem sorted, I pasted the result Iin the question

Comment: Sorry, didn't noticed there is typo in your code. See the answer.

Comment: wtf, why is too different add the [ ]??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation pipeline is **an array**. It should be wrapped in square brackets `[]`:

```
db.getCollection("metadata").aggregate(
    [
        {$unwind: '$tags'},
        {$group: {_id:'$tags.name', total: {$sum: 1}}},
        {$sort: {total: -1}}
    ]
);
```